# Visual studio Asp.net mvc, intellisense for javascript included in master file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

In the asp.net mvc project, while writing javascript in the each view, i wont be getting intellisense for javascripts referred to in the master page.

Is there any way to get intellisense in the page other than directly referring the javascript.

I know that in the external javascript files that i write, i will be able to get intellisense by putting

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.tmpl.js" />
/// <reference path="knockout-1.2.1.js" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery), you can download the plugin to do documentation I'm pretty sure it works on all pages. Using vs2010 it automatically does it I believe.
Also this goes straight to the [download](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js) , I should point out ScottGu's blog helped me on this.